# Proxy error Could not proxy request /api/v1

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

hello as you can see i have this proxy error

Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/v1/register from 192.168.1.19:3000 to http://192.168.1.19:3000.

my localhost is defined as http://localhost:3000/

what is the problem please?

i tried changing the proxy but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

you should use different ports one should be 3000 and another 4000(or any number) as you are sending req to backend